# Python : Create an Executbale for ARM processor Embedded Board

Tags: python

I have a program ready and build in i386 platform - but I now need to generate the code for ARM processor embedded board?

How can I create an executable on a i386 systems for ARM board?

Even if I port the code to ARM board - how can I build the executable on the same?

Comment: Chances are that it won't be possible to do for a while. You should give more details on the board that you're using. You'll need an interpreter for your processor architecture. Compiling python to machine code isn't yet possible as far as I know. Since python is interpreted you don't generate code for arm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python mainly depends on the interpreter beneath it, if there is no compiled interpreter for some processor architecture, your python code will not work.

The existing packaging applications, like PyInstaller, and freeze, will only package your python code (in the form of byte-code) with a copy of the running interpreter on the system, in the form of shared modules ".so" (in windows, the python interpreter will be packaged in .dll files).

I don't think you can package python application in a stand alone version on a computer with some processor architecture to work on a different computer (or embedded system) with different processor architecture, because the current packaging tools will not let you do that.

If you want to package python for ARM systems, package it on ARM system not on i386.

**Update**

If you really want to translate to machine code you can use **[pypy](http://pypy.org/features.html)** (which supports ARM platforms) or any of the RPython family (which puts some constraints on the Python language so that a variable's type can be inferred at compile time) with ARM support.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a *Python executable* as in *a Python program ready to run*, just save it to a text file and put `#!/usr/bin/env python` on the first line. It'll run on every platform that has a Python interpreter on it.

If you want to translate the Python code to machine code, just like [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org) or [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org), then I think you'll have to wait a little more as (afaik) tools are not yet ready / stable / working. But also keep in mind that packaging your Python software as an executable will *not* hide the structure of your python code from someone who really wants to look at it, if that's your goal.